# polling vs long polling

Tags: javascript, long-polling, polling

I got onto these [examples](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) showing polling vs long-polling in javascript, however I do not understand how they differ from one another. Especially regarding the long polling example, how does it keep its connection open?

This is what the traditional polling scenario looks like:

```
(function poll(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $.ajax({ url: "server", success: function(data){
      //Update your dashboard gauge
      salesGauge.setValue(data.value);

      //Setup the next poll recursively
      poll();
    }, dataType: "json"});
  }, 30000);
})();
```

and this is the long polling example:

```
(function poll(){
  $.ajax({ url: "server", success: function(data){
    //Update your dashboard gauge
    salesGauge.setValue(data.value);

  }, dataType: "json", complete: poll, timeout: 30000 });
})();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The difference is this: long polling allows for some kind of event-driven notifying, so the server is able to actively send data to the client. Normal polling is a periodical checking for data to fetch, so to say. Wikipedia is quite detailed about that:

With long polling, the client requests information from the server in a way similar to a normal polling; however, if the server does not have any information available for the client, then instead of sending an empty response, the server holds the request and waits for information to become available (or for a suitable timeout event), after which a complete response is finally sent to the client.

Long polling reduces the amount of data that needs to be sent because the server only sends data when there really IS data, hence the client does not need to check at every interval x.

If you need a more performant (and imho more elegant) way of full duplex client/server communication, consider using the WebSocket protocol, it's great!

Comment: Can the client tell the difference between long polling and a slow response? It seems to me that polling and long polling are basically the same thing. Polling: "Client: Is it ready yet? Server: No". Long Polling: "Client: Is it ready yet? Server: ... No".

Comment: @Davids: Here's the difference: With polling, the client asks and gets an immediate answer "yes/or". With long polling, the client asks but *does not* get an immediate answer. The server does not respond to the question until there *is* something that he can answer. So the question is pending all the time.

Comment: @Robert what happens if there is a timeout event and server is not able to send data in long polling? Should the client again send the same request?

Comment: @SaurabhShah that's right, long polling doesn't mean you have to get rid of periodical requests, if you have empty response it's completely natural to ask again for information from server

Comment: @Rob, why is long polling called long ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed: I have no clue. Names do not always have to make sense. Otherwise there wouldn't be any Jeffs in the world.

Comment: @Rob, 'Otherwise there wouldn't be any Jeffs in the world.' - what does it mean ? Do technical terms really have no need to make sense regarding nomenclature?

Answer (score 6):

The most important thing hasn't been explicitly described here: **Long polling is implemented server-side**.

*That's* why the Javascript code for long polling and polling looks about the same - the client doesn't really do anything different. The actual implementation of "Does this endpoint respond immediately or wait until it has a non-empty response?" is server-side code that resides on your webserver.

Your server is the one that decides when to respond. If it decides it may sometimes wait, then it's a long poll.

- Endpoint code that makes some changes in-memory and returns is a regular poll.
- Endpoint code that makes a slow SQL query and returns right after is a regular poll.
- Endpoint code that checks a message queue, sees it's empty, sleeps the thread a bit, and checks it again until the queue has something is a long poll.

The client just waits in any case.

- In "regular" polling, the response often comes back quickly - determined by latency and how long the server needs to process the request.
- In "long" polling, the response may still come back quickly, if the server only needs to wait briefly until it has something to respond with. But it may also take a while, because the server is willing to procrastinate its response so that it can respond with something useful.

From the client's perspective, it's basically the same. It sends a request, and at some point it gets a response. With long-polling it *may* be a little longer, but not necessarily.

Note that connections may timeout, so the example code wouldn't be used in production. You'd want some handling for timeouts and error responses, usually just retrying the request.

Comment: This is a far better and useful explanation than the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

So just my one cent, I think you should view option 2 as a better way of doing any form of polling. It's much cleaner/performant to only poll the server only after a response (success/failure). Which is pretty much-using recursion and `timeout` not `setTimeout`